# How to send push notification to specific user in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am looking to exchange messages between two users through push notifications..
I have been able to successfully send my pushes to parse, but have not be able to pass the message beyond that - to the targetUser...

Here is my code:

```
 var userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
     userQuery.whereKey("targetUser", equalTo: self.userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))


            let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
            pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
            pushQuery.whereKey("targetUser", matchesQuery: userQuery)

            //pushQuery.whereKey("targetUser", equalTo: self.userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))


            let push: PFPush = PFPush()
            push.setQuery(pushQuery)

            let textfields:NSArray = messageAlert.textFields as! NSArray
            let messageTextField: UITextField = textfields.objectAtIndex(0) as! UITextField

            push.setMessage(messageTextField.text)

            push.sendPushInBackground()

        }))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check for dups of this question?  Related links look promising.  Please consider using one of those and removing this one.

Comment: Please check out the documentation on the parse website, specifically:

https://parse.com/questions/sending-a-push-notification-from-one-user-to-another-user

It appears to have a tutorial of what you're trying to do.